# Unable to read stream chunks in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file, socket.io, stream

I have been trying to use socketio to stream files from nodejs server to the python socketio client. However I am unable read stream chunks. Inside the `data` event, variable `data2` has a value but when I log it, its value is not showing and is blank. How do I read the chunks into the array `data2` so I can emit the socketio event

```js
let readStream = createReadStream(req.file.path);
var data2 = "";
readStream.on('data', chunk => {
    // tried pushing it as it is and also strigifying it and then pushing it to array
    data2 += JSON.stringify(chunk);
    data2 += chunk;
});

console.log(data2);
socket.emit('file', data2);
```